# Phonegap Build error related to SQLLite

Tags: ios, sqlite, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

when I bulid a (previously ok) phongap app via build.phonegap.com, The IOS (only) build errors.
The error message is "Oh geez. Your build failed. Sorry, but a problem occurred on the build server".

Looking at the phonegap build log file, the error is here :

```
(.. directory path here ..) /Plugins/io.litehelpers.cordova.sqlite/SQLitePlugin.m:15:9: fatal error: 'Cordova/NSData+Base64.h' file not found

#import <Cordova/NSData+Base64.h>
```

It looks like Cordova/NSData+Base64.h isn't available on the phonegap build server ? I may be interpreting this wrongly.

In the config file we're using

```
<plugin name="io.litehelpers.cordova.sqlitestorage" spec="0.7.10" source="pgb" />
```

have also tried this to get latest version

```
<plugin name="io.litehelpers.cordova.sqlite"  source="pgb" />
```

and this

and have also added

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.2.0" />
```

as I gather 6.3.0 was added very recently.

Sadly this didn't fix the issue.

Any help on this would be gratefully received. Please let me know if more info is needed.

Thanks
Config file is

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="our.thing.changedforstackoverflow" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">

    <name>Our Application</name>

    <description>
    mobile application.
    </description>

    <author email="xyz@this.com" href="htp://here@there.com">
    XYZ company
    </author>

    <content src="index.html"/>
    <access origin="*"/>
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.2.0" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />

    <feature name="StatusBar">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true"/>
    </feature>

    <allow-navigation href="*"/>

    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="~1.1.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="~1.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.2.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~3.2.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.1.3" />
    <plugin name="io.litehelpers.cordova.sqlite"  source="pgb" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="1.2.0" source="pgb" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="1.0.1" source="pgb" />
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="~2.2.0" />

    <platform name="ios">
        <icon src="resources/ios/icons/Icon.png" width="57" height="57"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icons/Icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icons/Icon-29.png" width="29" height="29"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icons/Icon-40.png" width="40" height="40"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icons/Icon-40@2x.png" width="80" height="80"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icons/Icon-50.png" width="50" height="50"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icons/Icon-58.png" width="58" height="58"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icons/Icon-60.png" width="60" height="60"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icons/Icon-72.png" width="72" height="72"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icons/Icon72@2x.png" width="144" height="144"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icons/Icon-76.png" width="76" height="76"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icons/Icon-80.png" width="80" height="80"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icons/Icon-100.png" width="100" height="100"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icons/Icon-120.png" width="120" height="120"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icons/Icon-152.png" width="152" height="152"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icons/Icon-180@3x.png" width="180" height="180"/>
        <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default.png" height="1004" width="768"/>
        <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone_640x960.png" height="960" width="640"/>
        <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default~ipad.png" height="2008" width="1536"/>
        <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" height="480" width="320"/>
        <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone_640x1136.png" height="1136" width="640"/>
        <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-750@2x~iphone6-landscape_1334x750.png" height="750" width="1334"/>
        <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-750@2x~iphone6-portrait_750x1334.png" height="1334" width="750"/>
        <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-1242@3x~iphone6s-landscape_2208x1242.png" height="1242" width="2208"/>
        <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-1242@3x~iphone6s-portrait_1242x2208.png" height="2208" width="1242"/>
        <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad_2048x1496.png" height="1496" width="2048"/>
        <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad_2048x1536.png" height="1536" width="2048"/>
        <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad_1024x748.png" height="748" width="1024"/>
        <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad_1024x768.png" height="768" width="1024"/>
        <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad_1536x2008.png" height="2008" width="1536"/>
        <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad_1536x2048.png" height="2048" width="1536"/>
        <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad_768x1024.png" height="1024" width="768"/>
    </platform>

    <platform name="android">
        <icon src="resources/android/drawable-hdpi/icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
        <icon src="resources/android/drawable-ldpi/icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
        <icon src="resources/android/drawable-mdpi/icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
        <icon src="resources/android/drawable-xhdpi/icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
        <icon src="resources/android/drawable-xxhdpi/icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
        <icon src="resources/android/drawable-xxxhdpi/icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
        <splash src="resources/android/drawable-land-hdpi/screen.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
        <splash src="resources/android/drawable-land-ldpi/screen.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
        <splash src="resources/android/drawable-land-mdpi/screen.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
        <splash src="resources/android/drawable-land-xhdpi/screen.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
        <splash src="resources/android/drawable-land-xxhdpi/screen.png" density="land-xxhdpi"/>
        <splash src="resources/android/drawable-land-xxxhdpi/screen.png" density="land-xxxhdpi"/>
    </platform>

</widget>
```

Comment: Don't worry i had faced this issue .Sometime phonegap build server goes down. there is no issue with your plugins.

Comment: @HassanALi hi - actually it turns out there's a deeper problem with the build after a server update. More details here:  https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2187733

Comment: when I work out the real answer I'll post it here.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a good practice to keep using old plugins. You should use the [latest version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-sqlite-storage)? But since that version no longer supports PhoneGap Build, then use their [recommended alternative](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-sqlite-evcore-extbuild-free). Read the **BREAKING CHANGE** section to see if your code needs any modification and give it a spin.

Changing your config.xml from this

```
<plugin name="io.litehelpers.cordova.sqlite"  source="pgb" />
```

to this

```
<plugin name="cordova-sqlite-evcore-extbuild-free"  spec="0.8.0" />
```

Comment: thanks for this. The idea behind locking in to specific versions is for code stability, although this time that's backfired ! I've just learnt that using source="pgb" may be the (or a) problem in that the pgb repository is depricated, and we should use npm instead.  I don't know where I would have seen that post. Big learning curve here! But anyways .. As your replacement line doesn't state a source, what would it use? pgb or npm ?

Comment: npm is the default when you don't specify the source, which is exactly like most your other plugins (it's recommended to upgrade the other two `pgp` to `npm`). You can add `source="npm"` for clarity if you like. Yes, it's recommended to specify a version for stability (like I specified version `0.8.0` in my answer), but that's not to lock that version forever. That's only to allow you to control when to upgrade to a newer version, so you can do all required testing  before upgrading. It's recommended to check all plugins, test,  and upgrade at least twice a year.

Comment: that's great, and yes I agree with the controlled upgrade of plugins etc. thanks.